# web site com itens imagem do banco e paginacao

Tags: php, html, mysql

Como eu crio itens para um site tipo loja virtual.
 Puxar itens do BD e colocar paginação com limite de 15 itens.

Comment: O que voce já implementou?

Poste o codigo para que o pessoal possa te auxiliar, dessa forma fica muito vaga a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Quer o trabalho todo pronto, né ? rsrs

Irei te dar uma luz aqui ..

Para puxar os produtos do banco, usa-se:

```
SELECT * FROM meus_itens
```

Para puxar apenas 15 itens do banco, usa-se:

```
SELECT * FROM meus_itens LIMIT 15
```

Para paginar os resultados, o **LIMIT** recebe `LIMIT (Número de ítens passados), (Número de itens à mostrar)`, por exemplo, na página **um** a pesquisa deve ser:

```
SELECT * FROM meus_itens LIMIT 0, 15
```

Já na página **dois**, deve ser:

```
SELECT * FROM meus_itens LIMIT 15, 15
```

Página **três**:

```
SELECT * FROM meus_itens LIMIT 30, 15
```

E assim por diante, logo, terá de fazer uma lógica para pegar o número de uma página e transformar no dado que deseja.

No PHP, para fazer isso basta pegar um número da página, que pode ser um parâmetro GET por exemplo, subtrair 1 e multiplicar pelo número de registros que deseja: **((NUM_PAG - 1) * NUM_REG)** .. Ex:

```
<?php

@$pag = $_GET["pagina"];
$pagina = ( empty($pag) ? 1 : ( is_numeric($pag) && $pag > 0 ) ? (int) $pag : 1 ); // if inline
// verificando se o GET não está vazio, se é numero e maior que zero, se não, a variável recebe 1
$registros = 15;

// mágica do limit
$limit = ($pagina - 1) * $registros;

// query fica assim
$query = "SELECT * FROM meus_itens LIMIT ".$limit.", ".$registros;

echo $query;
// assumindo que $_GET["pagina"] seja um, seria impresso:
// SELECT * FROM meus_itens LIMIT 0, 15
```

Espero ter ajudado no chute inicial para você concluir o que deseja fazer.